# PG::SyntaxError: ERROR in Rails where clause with to_date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When I run this query...

```
OnlineCourseRegistration.where("exam_completed_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').to_date + 360 = ?", Date.today)
```

I get this error...

```
2.3.0 :012 >   OnlineCourseRegistration.where("exam_completed_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').to_date = ?", Date.today)
  OnlineCourseRegistration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "class_registrations".* FROM "class_registrations" INNER JOIN "course_classes" ON "course_classes"."id" = "class_registrations"."course_class_id" INNER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."id" = "course_classes"."course_id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "class_registrations"."user_id" WHERE (course_classes.class_type = 'online') AND (exam_completed_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').to_date = '2017-10-16')
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ...line') AND (exam_completed_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').to_date =...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "class_registrations".* FROM "class_registrations" INNER JOIN "course_classes" ON "course_classes"."id" = "class_registrations"."course_class_id" INNER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."id" = "course_classes"."course_id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "class_registrations"."user_id" WHERE (course_classes.class_type = 'online') AND (exam_completed_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').to_date = '2017-10-16')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ...line') AND (exam_completed_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').to_date =...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "class_registrations".* FROM "class_registrations" INNER JOIN "course_classes" ON "course_classes"."id" = "class_registrations"."course_class_id" INNER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."id" = "course_classes"."course_id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "class_registrations"."user_id" WHERE (course_classes.class_type = 'online') AND (exam_completed_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').to_date = '2017-10-16')
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:774:in `async_exec'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:774:in `exec_no_cache'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:138:in `block in exec_query'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:435:in `block in log'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:430:in `log'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:891:in `select'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:24:in `select_all'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:36:in `find_by_sql'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:585:in `exec_queries'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:471:in `load'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:220:in `to_a'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:598:in `exec_queries'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:471:in `load'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:220:in `to_a'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:573:in `inspect'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/marklocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

I have tried changing out quotes and backticks, but no luck.

Comment: I dont know ruby. But strftime is a ruby function and you are trying to use it as a postgresql function.

Comment: If you are looking for a Rails way: `OnlineCourseRegistration.where({ exam_completed_at: (Time.now.midnight - 361.day)..(Time.now.midnight - 360.day)})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much whaling and gnashing of teeth, I *think* I have the query I am looking for. I am still testing, but so far it seems to work.

Just to add some context to the original query I was trying to run. In plain English, I was trying to find records whose exam_completed_at date is one year previous to today's date. Said another way I am looking for records whos exam_completed_at date is today's date minus 360 (or one year).

Here is what I came up with:

```
OnlineCourseRegistration.where("exam_completed_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", DateTime.now.beginning_of_day - 1.year, DateTime.now.end_of_day - 1.year)
```

As a sanity check, check out this record:

```
  2.3.0 :276 > OnlineCourseRegistration.find 14340
D, [2017-10-17T10:01:54.622455 #35257] DEBUG -- :   OnlineCourseRegistration Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "class_registrations".* FROM "class_registrations" INNER JOIN "course_classes" ON "course_classes"."id" = "class_registrations"."course_class_id" INNER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."id" = "course_classes"."course_id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "class_registrations"."user_id" WHERE (course_classes.class_type = 'online') AND "class_registrations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 14340]]
 => #<OnlineCourseRegistration id: 14340, cart_id: 15093, user_id: 7090, course_class_id: 681, created_at: "2017-09-05 15:19:23", updated_at: "2017-10-17 13:29:08", exam_attempts: 0, exam_completed_at: "2016-10-17 13:29:03", evaluation_completed_at: nil, status: "Active", score: nil, add_extension: false, retest_cart_id: nil, retest_purchased_at: nil>
```

...and note the exam_completed_at date is `2016-10-17 13:29:03`. Now when I run the query, I get the same record returned:

```
2.3.0 :275 >  OnlineCourseRegistration.where("exam_completed_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", DateTime.now.beginning_of_day - 1.year, DateTime.now.end_of_day - 1.year)
D, [2017-10-17T09:59:27.832326 #35257] DEBUG -- :   OnlineCourseRegistration Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "class_registrations".* FROM "class_registrations" INNER JOIN "course_classes" ON "course_classes"."id" = "class_registrations"."course_class_id" INNER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."id" = "course_classes"."course_id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "class_registrations"."user_id" WHERE (course_classes.class_type = 'online') AND (exam_completed_at BETWEEN '2016-10-17 04:00:00.000000' AND '2016-10-18 03:59:59.000000')
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<OnlineCourseRegistration id: 14340, cart_id: 15093, user_id: 7090, course_class_id: 681, created_at: "2017-09-05 15:19:23", updated_at: "2017-10-17 13:29:08", exam_attempts: 0, exam_completed_at: "2016-10-17 13:29:03", evaluation_completed_at: nil, status: "Active", score: nil, add_extension: false, retest_cart_id: nil, retest_purchased_at: nil>, #<OnlineCourseRegistration id: 14267, cart_id: 15004, user_id: 7069, course_class_id: 681, created_at: "2017-07-15 22:06:06", updated_at: "2017-10-17 13:49:17", exam_attempts: 1, exam_completed_at: "2016-10-17 13:49:11", evaluation_completed_at: "2017-07-20 23:59:01", status: "Completed", score: "87", add_extension: false, retest_cart_id: nil, retest_purchased_at: nil>]>
```

Answer (score 2):

In [postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-formatting.html) you have `to_char` function to convert a date to string.

```
to_char(timestamp, text)
```

But you need a timestamp type so you need to use `current_timestamp`

So to get the timestamp from 360 days ago you use:

```
current_timestamp - interval '360 days'
```

To get an string with that date:

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/COVO43429)**

```
to_char(current_timestamp - interval '360 days', 'MM/dd/YYYY')
```

This generate a constant value so can be used with an index.

So your ruby code should be:

```
.where("exam_completed_at = to_char(current_timestamp - interval '360 days', 'MM/dd/YYYY')
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. It compares entire timestamp while we only need to compare the interval of days.

Comment: @MingJin Did you saw the demo? This convert timestamp to string. And because OP is using `strftime` we need convert the current time to string and that is what `to_char` do

Comment: Understand. but still will raise an operator error because it's comparing timestamp with date.

Comment: @MingJin mmmm I tought the field was string... but I just realize he convert to string and then back to date :/

Answer (score 0):

You have your SQL and ruby conflated.

`exam_completed_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').to_date` is Ruby code but you have it running in SQL.

One way to fix and use prettier AREL (assuming exam_completed_at is the database field to filter on and not a local variable) with a date range:

```
where(
  exam_completed_at: 
    (Date.today.beginning_of_day - 360.days)..(Date.today.end_of_day - 360.days)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
OnlineCourseRegistration.where("(created_at - current_timestamp) < interval '360 day'")
```

Comment: The problem is that wont use index on `exam_completed_at`. is better use `where(exam_completed_at = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '12 months')`